# How to find which property of an object threw the exception C#

Tags: c#, .net, exception, .net-4.0

Is there a way to find out which property of the objects threw the exception. I have a Class with 3 properties. I want to give a message to the user that a particular property in the class is wrong.

```
public class Numbers
{
    public string Num1 { get; set; }
    public string Num2 { get; set; }
    public string Num3 { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var numbers = new Numbers() { Num1 = "22", Num2 = "err", Num3 = "33" };
        // Call an extension method which tries convert to Int
        var num = numbers.Num1.StringToInt();
         num = numbers.Num2.StringToInt();
         num = numbers.Num3.StringToInt();

        Console.WriteLine(num);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public static class SampleExtension
{
    static StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace(true);

    // Extension method that converts string to Int
    public static int StringToInt(this string number)
    {
        try
        {
            // Intentionally used 'Convert' instead of 'TryParse' to raise an exception
            return Convert.ToInt32(number);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Show a msg to the user that Numbers.Num2 is wrong. "Input string not in correct format"
            var msg = stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().ToString();
            msg = ex.Message;
            msg += ex.StackTrace;
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using an extension method to convert sting to int. And i'm looking for a way to catch the wrong property in the extension method itself. I'm using **.Net framework 4.0**. Please suggest.

Comment: Properties are still methods. What does `.GetMethod()` gives for you when you walk in the stack trace?

Comment: Is there any reason why are you not using Exception class property StackTrace (ex.StackTrace) and using some static member property instead?

Comment: You can code extension method on Numbers type with argument of Expression that get property of Numbers type with lambda extension.

Comment: @Matías Fidemraizer `.GetMethod()`gives me the extension method name alone.

Comment: @GaneshKumar Ah, my friend. Let me compose the answer ;)

Comment: @user436730 I tried that as well. No luck

Answer (score 1):

I would use `Int32.TryParse` instead, then you can explicitly handle the failure to parse.

```
public static int StringToInt(this string number)
        {
            try
            {
                int result;
                if (!Int32.TryParse(number, out result))
                {
                    // handle the parse failure
                }
                return result;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm trying to capture the property name. Irrespective of what kind of conversion mechanism we are using, My intention was to find out which is the property that called this method and resulted in an error

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int StringToInt(this Numbers number,
 Expression<Func<Numbers, string>> prop)
{
    try
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(prop.Compile()(number));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var expression = (MemberExpression)prop.Body;
        string name = expression.Member.Name;
        throw new MissingMemberException(string.Format("Invalid member {0}", name));
    }
}
```

And call it:

```
var num = numbers.StringToInt(p=>p.Num1);
```

Comment: Tried that. prop doesn't have the name of the property. It has some data like this  _{Method = {System.String <Main>b__2(Sample.Numbers)}}_

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply supply all needed data to the method during call? Schematically (you can extend it):

```
public static int ToInt(string number, string info)
{
    try
    {
        // ...
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(info);
    }
}

// and usage
string str1 = "123";
int n = ToInt(str1, "Trying to parsing str1");
```

Comment: I tried to put some sample code. I'm trying to implement this is a very large system. We cannot imagine changing all the parameters and hardcode the property name. That is the reason I'm trying to find a generic way.

Answer (score 0):

## Note

#### I was answering this question based on .NET 4.5 because the question had no tag for an specific framework version. I leave the answer here because it may be useful for future visitors using .NET 4.5.

I would like to say that your code sample is very ugly since you could overcome this problem by using `int.TryParse`, but as I guess you wanted to show a generalized case (bad choice) and you just want to know the caller name of the extension method: **check the `[CallerMemeberNameAttribute]` introduced in the 4.5 version of .NET Framework:**

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute.aspx

For example, either in an extension or regular method, do this:

```
public void Method([CallerMemberName] string callerName)
{
}
```

And the CLR will set the input parameter with the name of the caller!

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to rise an exception, that is the reason why I didn't use `TryParse`. My intension was to apply the solution on a larger system. i've just scribbled some code to bring the context. Anyways, I'm using ** .Net framework 4.0 **. Is there any work around for that

Comment: @GaneshKumar You should tag the question with the framework version.

Comment: @GaneshKumar It's harder. One option could be PostSharp. Are you familiar with AOP?

Comment: Missed to tag the framework version. I did that just now. I'm not that good at PostSharp, but it is implemented in the  code. Any suggestions how to do it using PostSharp would help. Thanks